# MySQL Group Replication or a Single Server is enough?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, replication, database-replication

I'm planning to create a system which tracks visitors clicks into the database. I'm expecting around 1M inserts/day into the Database.

On the backend, I'll have an analytics system which will analyze all the data that's been collected over the days/weeks/months/years.

My question is: is it a practical approach to have 2 different MySQL Servers + 1 Web server? MySQL Server A would insert the clicks into it's DB and it would be connected to MySQL Server B by group replication, so whenever I create reports, etc on MySQL Server B, it doesn't load Server A heavily.

These 2 Database servers would then be connected to the Web Server which would handle all the click requests and displaying the backend reports also.

Is it a practical solution, or is it better to have one bigger server to handle all the MySQL data? Or have multiple MySQL servers that are load balancing each other? Anything else perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1M inserts/day is not a high load by modern standards. That's less than 12 per second on average.

On sufficiently powerful servers with fast storage and [proper tuning of MySQL options](https://www.slideshare.net/inner/mysql-performance-tuning-part-1-mysql-configuration-includes-mysql-57), you can expect to support at least 100x that load with a single MySQL server.

A better reason to use multiple MySQL servers is **redundancy**. Inevitably, any MySQL server needs to be upgraded, or you might have hardware failures and need to replace a disk, or other components. To avoid downtime, you should have a standby database server, which stays in sync with the primary server, either using MySQL replication or by disk-level replication like DRBD.